# Access parameters from past intents Dialogflow Fulfillment

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es

[Intent example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3DX8t.png) [Intent example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gqCL2.png) I'm trying to access different parameters from past intents, but with this code it will only get the last parameter. The last intent where the fulfillment is triggered is 'Dias20' and it will only get the parameter 'Dias20', the other ones raise me an error--> 'undefined'. I have tried everything to retrieve the context and then the parameters but there is no way. it is a tree type conversation where every intent has a followup intent with input context the last intent and output the current intent.

```
function CalcularScore(agent)
{

    //coger los parametros 
    //var contextIn = agent.getContext('resp-followup');
    const respiracion = agent.contexts['resp-followup'].parameters.Respiracion;
    //const respiracion = agent.parameters.Respiracion;
    const fiebre = agent.parameters.Fiebre;
    const muco = agent.parameters.Muco;
    const muscular = agent.parameters.Muscular;
    const gastro = agent.parameters.Gastro;
    const dias20 = agent.parameters.Dias20;

    agent.add('tu score es: ' + respiracion );

 }
```

Comment: Although you describe the Intents as using Followup Intents, it would help a lot more if you could update your question to include screen shots of the exact Intents to show the Input and Output Contexts and the parameters for each one. The more information you provide in your question, the better chances we have of being able to help you. See [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more guidelines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could work given the info you provided:

```
let params = agent.getContext("resp-followup").parameters;
let respiracion = params.Respiracion;
```

If this does not work try setting the context in the prior intent fulfillment like this:

```
agent.setContext({ name: 'context_name', lifespan: 5, parameters: { param_name: agent.parameters.Respiracion}});
```

Then:

```
let params = agent.getContext("context_name").parameters;
let respiracion = params.param_name;
```

Note: replace context_name and param_name with whatever you like. Also if you want you can increase lifespan depending on how many intents later you need the data.